# How to apply ng-hide to a button when a particular tab is active?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am building an employee management app using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/). I'm having some trouble with something that seems like it should be really simple and it's driving me nuts! I have this setup like this with a `<md-tabs>` and a `<md-button>`

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
<md-tab label="active">
</md-tab>
<md-tab label="terminated">
</md-tab>
</md-tabs>
<md-button></md-button>
```

All I want to do is make the `<md-button>` disappear when the "terminated" tab is active. I know that I need to apply ng-hide to the button, but I cannot figure out how to reference the active tab.

Comment: What markup is this?

Comment: The above markup is Angular-Material @SumanBarick

Comment: why not just put button inside label active tab?

Comment: @singhakash The button is a FAB that I want to be outside the tabs.

Comment: you can use ng-init with ng-click on tabs and ng-if on button . `ng-init="showbutton=true"`,`ng-click="showButton=true` on active label, ,`ng-click="showButton=false` on terminated, and `ng-if="showButton"` on button

Comment: @singhakash That did it! Thanks so much! If you submit your solution as an answer, then I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the md-selected directive on your md-tabs tag to bind the active tab to a property of your controller with something like this:

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedTab">
```

Then you can reference the controller property in ng-show, ng-if, ng-hide as necessary.

(The approach mentioned in the comments above will work, but it's more work than is necessary.)

In lieu of a pre-existing controller, you can just create "tabController" something like this:

```
app.controller('tabController' 
    function ($scope) {
        selectedTab = 0
    }
)
```

Because your button is outside of your tabs you'd have to load the controller on the containing element. If you have a controller at that leve, you can just add the selectedTab property to it.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't quite understand. How do I "reference the controller property"? I did not set up a controller for the tabs as they are not dynamic.

Comment: If you don't have a controller then the first approach is probably ok. ng-init is generally frowned on though. I'll edit my answer to show the controller.